# Finding pitch/yaw values from lookat vector

Tags: opengl, c++, 3d, mathematics

I have a camera class that contains a position, a pitch, and a yaw (the pitch and the yaw correspond to y and x rotation values). I want to implement a lookAt function that takes a vector and the function changes the pitch and yaw so it's looking at that point in space. However, I cannot seem to find the math equation to do it (various ones online, none seem to work). How would I be able to implement it?

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
struct Camera
{
    Vec3 position;
    float pitch, yaw;

    void lookAt(Vec3 center)
    {
        //????
    }

    mat4x4 toTransform() //How I convert the values to a matrix (if this is relevant)
    {
        return CreateLookAtMatrix
            position,
            position + Vec3(cos(pitch)*sin(yaw), sin(pitch), cos(pitch)*cos(yaw)),
            Vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please stop using Euler angles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've already got the answer in your matrix function:

`lookAt = position + Vec3(cos(pitch)*sin(yaw), sin(pitch), cos(pitch)*cos(yaw))`

You just need to do a little algebra to get the yaw and pitch variables over to the left.

To start with the simplest expression, the y-axis gives:

```
lookAt.y = position.y + sin(pitch), which we can rearrange to...
sin(pitch) = lookAt.y - position.y
pitch = asin(lookAt.y - position.y)
```

Where asin is [arcsine, the inverse of sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions).

Note that this assumes `lookAt - position` is a unit vector (length 1) which in your matrix expression is true by construction. If `center` can be anywhere then you'll want to start by constructing the unit vector you need:

```
void lookAt(Vec3 center)
{
   Vec3 direction = (center - position).normalized;
   pitch = asin(direction.y);
   yaw = atan2(direction.x, direction.z);
}
```

I skipped ahead a bit on yaw there because we have both `k*sin(yaw)` and `k*cos(yaw)` for some real `k`, so we can just drop that into [the atan2 convenience function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) and let it sort out all the cases for us. ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Saved me tonnes of time. Just one quick remark: for some reason I had to add `PI` to the last equation.

Comment: It will vary based on how you measure your bearings. in OP's `LookAtMatrix` code, they used `cos(yaw)` for `z`, and `sin(yaw)` for `x`, which means a yaw of zero is facing along `z+`, and a yaw of `π/2` is facing along `x+`. If your angle convention is different, then you might need to offset or even negate the angle generated by these formulas, since they're derived from OP's conventions.